# Can't start PyChess

Tags: release-freya, gtk, apps

I've installed PyChess (http://www.pychess.org/download/)
But when I started I get this message:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
(pychess:17640): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
(pychess:17640): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've done

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk*
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```

But still not working.. Any ideas?

Updated:

```
sudo apt-cache policy pychess
pychess:
  Installed: 0.12~beta3-1
  Candidate: 0.12~beta3-1
  Version table:
     *** 0.12~beta3-1 0
    500 http://py.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: add output of `apt-cache policy pychess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got same error, while trying to solve this post.

Installation from terminal command `sudo apt-get install pychess`

we will get `beta3` version, which is very old. (Refer [here](https://github.com/pychess/pychess/issues/1055#issuecomment-159736064)).

Now download  [0.12.deb](http://www.pychess.org/download/pychess_0.12-1_all.deb) and install from software center.

**Note**: No need to remove installed pychess, you will get `upgrade` option.

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Comment: did you do this?
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk*

sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386

Comment: No, those errors/warnings are nothing to do with `pychess` @td18

Comment: @td18 Please follow the answer and let me know :)

Comment: I've installed from the software centre but I still having those errors.

Also when I do  pychess --version
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(pychess:7904): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(pychess:7904): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
pychess 0.12beta3 (Anderssen)

Comment: @td18 Please run `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module` and add output of `apt-cache policy pychess` to question :)

Comment: @td18 those are warnings not errors. Are you able to open pychess?

Comment: no, it doesn't open the app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32155/discussion-between-ravan-and-td18).

Comment: Problem solved by installing the  0.12.deb installer as is mentioned above. cool.